CORS Policy Blocking Fetch Request in Chatbot Application
I'm developing a chatbot application using React for the frontend (running on localhost:3000) and Flask for the backend API (running on 127.0.0.1:5000). I'm encountering a CORS policy error whenever I try to send a fetch request from my frontend to my backend. The error message is:
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This error pops up whenever I type something into the chat interface, triggering the fetch request to the /predict endpoint on the backend. Here's the fetch request code from my React app:
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ message: userInput })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

And here's the relevant part of my Flask backend:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    data = request.get_json()
    # Process the data
    response = {"reply": "Processed message"}
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I've already tried enabling CORS in Flask using flask_cors.CORS(app), but the issue persists. I'm looking for advice on how to properly configure CORS or any other setup that might resolve this error.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Self duplicate of CORS policy error when fetching POST request in Flask app from React frontend

Try changing CORS in your Flask setup.
When my team created an API for Flask, we encountered the same problem and this setting helped us.
CORS(app, resources={r"/predict": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}})


Also you can try adding a new header to your POST request:
"Origin": "http://localhost:3000"


The CORS config already allows requests from all origins. How is restricting it more a solution?

And you can't modify the Origin header on the request. And the origin is already http://localhost:3000, so this would do absolutely nothing.
